# How to reference a file in a different folder in a C# solution

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I wonder if anyone could assist me..

I am working in a Visual Studio project, and we have recently begun working on Unit Tests for our project.

The Unit Tests rely on referencing an Excel file in the solution.

We have added code that appears to work well on each of our own environments with regards to referencing the file, and all seems good.

We have now also setup TFS to trigger it to run all the Unit Tests on each commit with a report, which has now shown to have some problems as almost all of them are failing, despite them all running successfully on our own environments.

TFS doesn't seem to provide any logging why the tests are failing, but we assume it's to do with the path referencing.

So our solution structure is like so..

```
..\head\Solution\Project\project.csproj
..\head\Solution\Tests\TestFiles\spreadsheet.xlsx
```

We are currently using the following code to reference the spreadsheet..

```
string filename = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName, "Tests\\TestFiles\\spreadsheet.xlsx");
ExcelImporter importer = new ExcelImporter(filename);
```

Seems like we are explicitly calling a set number of parent folders, which probably isnt the same on the build server environment.

How can we better reference the spreadsheet file, assuming we'll never know how many parent folders to the solution there will be to it?

Comment: FYI what you do isn't an unittest anymore as soon as you touch the file system.

Comment: Why don't you use simply config files `AppSettings` to get the excel file path?

Comment: First, TFS should report exceptions in unit tests. Either there was no exception or there is a problem with the tests' configuration. Second, if the data files are in the same project as the tests, just change the `Copy to Output Directory` action to `Copy Always` and use paths relative to the project to read them

Comment: Turns out that we can view the test logs when viewing the build results from Visual Studio. Couldnt figure out why TFS doesnt show this information after double checking the configuration, etc. But at least now we know where we can see these results. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Unit tests project create a folder, let's call it "Resources", and copy your file there. Make sure the file properties set your file to be always copied to the output.

Then in your unit test just get the file like this:

```
string filename = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Resources\\spreadsheet.xlsx");
```

Relevant link: [Enviroment.CurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You don't even need the `Path.Combine`, a relative path is enough. A test's current directory is the output directory

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution my team ultimately decided to with and the files are being referenced correctly with. thanks!

With regards to TFS not showing the exception, turns out you can only view level of detail within Visual Studio, and not from the TFS website? But its cool that we know where to see these results now anyways.

Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help, although I have to admit Davide Piras's solution is more elegant.

Answer (score 4):

I really would not got this way, the physical path where your unit tests will be running from might be very different on the build server compared to your local dev machines.

in general you should simply include (even adding it as a link) a reference to the solution item (excel file) in your unit test project and then you can set its property to copy to output folder so that when unit tests assembly is generated the excel file will also be copied in the same location as the assembly of unit tests, then at the top of your test method you can declare the dependency in this way with the standard attribute:

```
[DeploymentItem("spreadsheet.xlsx")]
```

this should work well for MS Tests at least, we use it and works with no issues.

Comment: Isn't `Copy Always` enough? Unless TFS removes some of the build artefacts, the Excel file will be there when the test runs.

Comment: Thanks Davide, good response. After consulting with the team about the best solution to go for, we decided on Avdomingo's suggestion about structuring the folders a little differently and improving the path reference.
Seemed to have done the trick.

Thanks for the suggestion nonetheless! :)